# cookie is expired when browser closed for a html file locating on harddrive

Tags: javascript, cookies

It is a html file with Javascript which is located on my computer (not real home page).
I am using following JavaScript code to add a cookie, the cookie is stil alive when I don't close the browser but when I close the browse the cookie does not exist any more. How do I make the cookie survive in 4 days even when you close the browser?

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
setCooike("name", "test", 4);

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
getCookie("name") returns ""??
```

Comment: `for a html file locating on harddrive` - there is no strict rules how to handle cookies (or any other information) for local files, so best you can do is use remote or local server. Check XAMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a setting in your browser to clear your cookies when you close it. So it cannot be resolved by code, some users will have this setting enabled and won't want to use cookies so you should plan for that situation.